# ng-view doesn't evaluate bootstrap javascript (css and so on)

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

My problem is, when Angular load templateUrl (through $routeProvider) inside ng-view it doesn't evaluate all javascript as well. I tried to figure it out, but now i'm really confused. During my search i found a lots of new topic, and i've lost in them. Any idea?

**Tale**

I tried to figure it out if anybody else met this problem before, or if there are any solution for this problem. The way i've found was something like "lazy-loading" directives or using requirejs, but i'm not sure if those tools are really solves this problems.

As Buu Nguyen mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220197/angularjs-does-not-load-scripts-within-ng-view)

> That's the way jqLite works. If you want scripts in templates to be
>   evaluated, include jQuery before AngularJS. If jQuery is included, the
>   script will be evaluated. Try removing jQuery, and you see the
>   originally observed behavior.

I've tried, including jquery before angularjs but doesn't cause any effect at all.
There are sevaral threads i read, for example

- [stack-overflow-19434249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434249/angular-js-how-to-load-js-files-in-partials)
- [stack-overflow-12197880](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include)
- [stack-overflow-21994037](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994037/expression-evaluation-not-working-in-several-ng-view)

but nothing lead to solution (maybe i've missed a thing). And i think, this is not even my problem. I don't want to (re)load javascript files, i just want to force evaluate my bootstrap.

Honestly i'm really confused now. 
Afterward first time i met RequireJS. (lazy loading, and friends, again)

I've watched [Thomas Burleson's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yulGISBF8w) on youtube and i nearly understand what is it. And i looked much more articles in topic (because i found it's interest) but solution should be somewhere else.

**Here is the situation**

While i'm working on my angularjs app, i've made a partial site as separated .html file (just in case) and it seems pretty. Then i cut this .html file to pieces (header, top-menu, content, footer) and use its body tag as div inside a partial urlTemplate.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" id="page-top">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navigation">
            <div top-menu></div>
        </div>

        <div ng-view></div>

        <footer id="page-footer">
           <div class="container">
                 <span>Copyright © 2014. All Rights Reserved.</span>
                 <span class="pull-right"><a href="#page-top" class="roll">Go to top</a></span>
           </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

angular $routeprovider:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'main/templates/main.html'
        }).when('/ad-element', {
            templateUrl: 'submit/templates/submit.html'
        }).when('/404', {
            templateUrl: 'errors/templates/404.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/404'
        });
    }]);
```

submit.html

```
<div class="page-sub-page page-submit">
    <div ng-controller="SubmitController" class="container">
          <form ...></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every angular function is working, the only visible difference is the appearance.

This is the good one:
[image: good]

And this is the bad one:
[image: bad]

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I am having the same issues. Any input will help. Thanks