# Using ng-view and loading the controller on demand

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I am using ng-view in an attempt to re-use common page elements. Perhaps I am mis-understanding the point of view and it's not appropriate here.

Basically, I have an html page that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- css and js here including index.js -->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <navigation-bar/>
        <div ng-view />
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what my index.js looks like

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'], function ($routeProvider) {});
    angular.module('app').controller("ctrl", function ($scope, $log, $q, $timeout) {});
    angular.module('app').config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when("/management", {
                    templateUrl : "/experiment/management.html",
                    // Is there a way to load /experiment/managementController.js here?
                }
                })
            ]);
    })();
```

My management.html

```
<div ng-controller="managementController">
<!-- A bunch of code -->
</div>
```

And managementController.js (which I would like to run only when the route is loaded)

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app').controller("managementController", [
            "$scope", "$sce", "$log", function ($scope, $sce, $log) {
                // controller specific code
            }
        ]);
})();
```

Why do I want to do this? Because I have many, many potential views with many potential controllers. (On the order of 50)

Is this not possible or not the intent of ng-view?

If it's not the intent of ng-view, is there something that could help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look at the first example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) in the docs. Check out the script.js tab.

```
$routeProvider.when("/management", {
                    templateUrl : "/experiment/management.html",
                    controller: 'managementController',

                }
```

If you meant that you want to load the actual file, [take a look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434249/angular-js-how-to-load-js-files-in-partials)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resolve` property in `angular Js` which can handle dynamically loading the script containing the target controller and resolve the promise once the load is complete.

for example:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/management',
        {
            templateUrl: '/experiment/management.html',
            resolve: resolveController('/app/controllers/managementController.js')
        });
```