# how can I include controller in router provider stage?

Tags: angularjs

I found the code:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
  app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/main',{
         templateUrl:"mainView.html",
         controller:mainController
       })
       .when('/anyName',{
         templateUrl:"templates/view3.html",
         controller:temp3Controller
       })
  });
```

What if I want to include the file in router stage by using just `file` for example? such as

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
  app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when('/main',{
         templateUrl:"mainView.html",
         controller:mainController
         files: ["css/mainController.css", "js/mainController.js"]
       })
       ...
  });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Casey I want to have a lazy load without add up all file into index.html file.

Comment: @NilesTanner There are only one module, don't you think that it is single page app?

Comment: @DotKu doing a bit of research it looks like the router isn't the right place to do this. I would look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656231/angularjs-dynamic-loading-of-external-js-based-on-routes

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this.  The typical way to improve performance is to combine the files into one file at runtime and avoid the overhead of multiple requests.

Comment: @DotKu Could u please look into this url,might help u for lazy loading.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434249/angular-js-how-to-load-js-files-in-partials